# Training a function that maps n-dim to n-dim

Tags: multivariate-analysis, terminology, algorithms, signal-processing, spectral-analysis

As an example, say the input is an array of numbers representing an audio snippet and the output is a transformed/filtered version of it.

What would be the proper term for that?
Which are examples of algorithms for the job?

**EDIT:**
More specifically, I want to train audio source separation. The input is a mixed sound (spectrogram) and the output is the sound with some energy removed in certain frequencies. The function needs to recognize some pattern in the input and decide what to remove.

Comment: What is the meaning of the relationship between the sets of variables? Does every variable in the first group contribute to every variable in the second group?

Comment: They do. I've edited the question.

Comment: Your description of the problem might be usefully understood as a *linear projection* from one (high dimensional) vector space into a substantially lower dimensional subvectorspace.  Since you know that the projection simply removes some frequencies, what kind of "training" is even needed?  Are you trying to identify which frequencies are removed?